# Can`t mark the elements in Div pop up in chrome while using Selenium automation

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

While automating in [automationpractice.com](http://automationpractice.com/index.php),
Steps:
1.open "automationpractice.com/index.php?id_product=5&controller=product#/size-s/color-orange"
2. click "Add to Cart" button
3. Below add to Cart successfully pop-up displayed(Refer to below screenshot)

Now I cannot mark any elements in this pop up. I tried `XPath` which is inside the parent window with Div tag, but The error is ElementNotVisible. I tried it with `driver.getWindowHandles()`, but it shows that only 1 window exists(Parent window). Also tried with `alert`, but it says no alert exists.

This issue only occurs in the Chrome browser, for firefox , it works fine using xpath inside parent window with Div tag.

Below is the script I tried, can anyone kindly help on this? Thank you in advance!

The xpath for this pop up is `"//*[@id="layer_cart"]/div[2]"`

```
Set<String> windows = wd.getWindowHandles();
System.out.println("windows.size():"+ windows.size()); // the result is 1
```

[image]

Comment: First hand impression is that your xpath is not correct. Please check it again. And also, you need to specify the element you need to search. This is not a pop up, or an alert or a window, so these things won't work on here.

Comment: Thank you first. I don`t know why you cannot see the popup, please refer to the above steps and  screen shot. e.g. I want to click Proceed to checkout button, the XPath for it is //*[@id="layer_cart"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/a/span . the same XPath is worked in Firefox .

Answer (score 0):

There is no new window or alert on this page, only problem is your XPATH cotains `"` instead of `'`, alo need to wait a few seconds for that element to be visible:

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_product=2&controller=product");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form[@id='buy_block']//p[@id='add_to_cart']")).click();

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='blockcart_caroucel']/li[1]")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='blockcart_caroucel']/li[1]")).click();
```

Comment: Thank you Kushal, It should be have a pop up displayed, after clicked Add to Cart in product detail page. you can refer to my above screenshot. I don`t think that XPath include " is the problem, since other XPath also include " works fine. also I add the implicit wait before to mark the elements.